Urban fantasy. Normal guy learns about werewolves and is taught to hunt them by a female werewolf hunter
I read a series years ago about a normal guy who accidently discovers that werewolves and shape shifters and vampires exist.
I don't remember everything but there was a woman who hunts supernatural creatures that takes the guy under her wing and teaches him how to be a hunter.
They also had wooden weapons that they treated with a special serum that allowed them to hurt supernatural creatures and also change shape when the user concentrated on it.
There were two classes of werewolf; one was humans that were infected and they were strong and fast but could be killed by the main characters. The other class was pure-blooded natural-born werewolves and they were immensely powerful and the humans had no chance of defeating one on their own.

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Possibly the Dresden Files series by Jim Butcher? The second of these, Fool Moon, has various different types of werewolves (although I think there were more than two).

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about when you read this?

I read the series in the early 2000's maybe about 15 years ago

It wasn't the dresden files, I've looked into that possibility but it's definitely not that
